# How to find out what views page you're looking at

Tags: 7, views

I have the `$is_portfolio` variable in my "template.php" file that lets me easily check what content type is being displayed, so I can do freaky and awesome stuff with it:

```
function mycooltheme_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'page' ) {
    if ($variables['node']->type == 'portfolio') {
      $variables['is_portfolio'] = TRUE;
    }
    else {
      $variables['is_portfolio'] = FALSE;
    }       
  }
}
```

In my "page.tpl.php" file, I use it through a conditional which lets me change the markup depending on the content type:

```
<?php if ($is_portfolio) : ?>
  // Use this layout
<?php elseif (!$is_portfolio) : ?>
  // Boo, use this layout instead :-(
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can my code in "template.php" be customized so it can also check which **Views page** is being displayed, so I can target those as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [menu_get_item()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal--includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) to retrieve the page callback for the currently shown path, and check it correponds to 'views_page', which means you are in a view.

```
function mycooltheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $menu_item = menu_get_item($_GET['q']);

  if ($menu_item['page_callback'] == 'views_page') {
    $vars['is_portfolio'] = ($menu_item['page_arguments'][0] == 'path_of_your_view');
  }
}
```

You can also use [current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/current_path/7) directly, but I found interesting to know that you're on a Views page using `menu_get_item()`.

Comment: Thanks for this man. I'll try it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative you can use

```
$view = views_get_page_view();
$name = $view->name;
```